# JavaScript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript

Hi whats wrong in this code, where is the syntax error..  i got that error:

NOTE: The first block of code is where chrome detect error on autosizeProgress.

But even if i delete this block the error is still there:

EDIT 2:

I found the error!!

```
<script>
// JavaScript object for later use
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player',/* Options */); <--
// ...
</script>
```

By the way just like a note. the code is working.. i can see the video, but i dont want an error on console. thanks

```
 <script>
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
  // if the <video width> is not specified, this is the default
  defaultVideoWidth: 530,
  // if the <video height> is not specified, this is the default
  defaultVideoHeight: 377,
  autosizeProgress: true,
  // Hide controls when playing and mouse is not over the video
  features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume','sourcechooser','fullscreen'],
  alwaysShowControls: false,
});
</script>
```

I also rewrite it to see if there where no illegal chars overthere, =( i cant found the problem

Comment: I have disable all plugins, just leave Jquery and Mediaelementplayer. and i got the error, what can i do?

Comment: Which browser are you using and what console? I have run your code in chrome and I don't see any error. This is the code I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/3MzDE/

Comment: will update the question, cause i delete the code and the error still there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In older version of `IE` the extra comma in the object literal will throw syntax errors:

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
  defaultVideoWidth: 530,
  defaultVideoHeight: 377,
  autosizeProgress: true,
  features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume','sourcechooser','fullscreen'],
  alwaysShowControls: false //Extra Comma Removed
}); //added ;
```

Comment: But would that throw this error? (I don't have IE, I cannot test it).

Comment: @Felix I forget the exact exception IE throws in the event of an extra comma.  I know its a syntax exception, I will test.

Comment: yes i was editing the code in question, cause that ; wasent missing, i missed copied.. also im in chrome, copied your code, but still have the same issue, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )... SO thanks but your answer didnt fix the problem

Comment: Since you are in Chrome you can pinpoint where error occurred. In Console view on the left hand side of error there is triangle with which you can uncollapse error report to see where exactly it happened. At least you can eliminate which script causes it.

Comment: actually thats the way i knew where was the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ),,, otherwise i just see "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" i have to uncollapse to see this

Comment: i found the error but i would give correct answer to you cause you point an error i havent notice as i am testing on chrome now , thanks